# Apply cupy.linalg.svd over a stack of matrices

Tags: python, cupy

I'd like to perform SVD (singular value decomposition) via `cupy.linalg.svd` over a stack of matrices, computing the SVD per-matrix.

```py
import cupy as cp
arr = cp.random.uniform(size=(1000, 3, 3), dtype=cp.float32)
sing_vals = cp.linalg.svd(arr, compute_uv=False, full_matrices=False)
```

This gives an error claiming that `arr` is not 2D. Apparently, `cp.linalg.svd` can only compute the SVD of a single 2D matrix. However, `numpy.linalg.svd` computes the SVD always over the last two axes of an array which is much more powerful.

---

**Is there a way to efficiently compute the SVD over a stack of matrices in `cupy`?**

Better yet, is there a general method to efficiently `apply_along_axis`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation of CuPy calls `cusolverDn<t>gesvd()`, which does not support batch computation.  For an efficient batch computation, I suppose CuPy has to invoke a CUDA API that receives batched inputs.

FYI to improve CuPy, cuSOLVER has `cusolverDn<t>gesvdjBatched()` and `cusolverDn<t>gesvdaStridedBatched()`, which seem possible to be used for batched SVD (of dense general matrices).  I don't have an idea on the difference among SVD algorithms.  `j` stands for Jacobi method and `a` stands for approximate.